# How to add frame title into toc in beamer?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[13pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\useoutertheme{miniframes} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
%\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=myblue}
%\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=Green}
%\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{bg=myblue}
%\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
%}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
\useinnertheme{circles}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.13}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} % UBC Blue (primary)
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=Mahogany]{structure} % Sample dvipsnames color
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[ball]

\usepackage{graphicx,,tabularx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{ragged2e}
 
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\title[PDWP]{Provincial Development Working Party}
\author{Engineer Muhammad Imran} % Your name
\institute[Chief P.B] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{\color{darkgreen}{\large{ Public Building Sector \\\medskip
\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=3cm]{logo}\\\medskip
P \& D Board, Lahore}}  \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip

\textit{chiefpb@gmail.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ Contents}
\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A Bird's Eye View}

\centering
 \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{15cm}|}\hline
 \textbf{ Name of Scheme} & Construction Of Police Training
School, Rawat, District Rawalpindi.\\\hline
  \textbf{Location} & Rawalpindi\\\hline
 \textbf{ Sponsoring Agency} & Police Department, Government of Punjab\\\hline
  \textbf{Executing Agency} & C \& W Department Government of Punjab\\\hline
 \textbf{ Cost} & \begin{itemize} \item Original: Rs.602.590 Million \item 1st revised : Rs.671.346 Million \item 2nd Revised: Rs.721.813 Million\end{itemize}\\\hline
  \textbf{Upto Date Expenditure} & Rs.424.60 Million\\\hline
 \textbf{ Implementation Period} & 57 Months (Till June 2021)\\\hline
\textbf{Source of Funding} &\begin{itemize}\item ADP 2020-21at G.S: 3289 \item  Allocation: Rs.10.00 Million\end{itemize}\\\hline

\end{tabular}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Project Description}
\begin{block}{i}
 PTSR Rawalpindi was established on 1st July, 1986 and up-graded to the status of Police Training School in July 2002. \end{block}
\begin{block}{ii} This training institution was shifted to the premises of Punjab Constabulary Battalion No. 2 Rawat in 04 barracks comprising 48 rooms / dormitories temporarily. Presently, the barracks are being used as class rooms.\end{block}
\begin{block}{iii} With the passage of time, intake of trainees of various courses is increasing and the existing class rooms were in-sufficient to cater the imminent requirements. \end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Project Description}
\begin{block}{iv}
Accordingly, scheme for construction of Police Training School, Rawat, Rawalpindi was approved for Rs 602.590 million. 
\end{block}
\begin{block}{v}
 The Sponsors  submitted 1st revised  PC-1 at a cost of Rs. 671.346   million
\end{block}
\begin{block}{vi}
Now, the Sponsors has submitted 2nd revised  PC-1 at a cost of Rs. 721.813 million for consideration of PDWP.
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Reasons of Revision}
\begin{itemize}
\item The scheme was split into 19 groups. However, 4 groups remained un-allotted. 
\item New MRS rates for un-allotted civil works.
\item Rs 7.448 million for Price variation for Group-1 () as per clause 55 of contract agreement. 
\item Rs. 8.654 Million of 5\% PST in revised cost estimate.
\item Rs.5.228 million for payment of outstanding amount of price variation under writ petition filed by contractor in Lahore High Court, Rawalpindi Bench, Rawalpindi. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Project Scope}
\begin{block}{Construction of Three Storey Building for Police Training School:52392 sq ft }

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction   of   three   storey   Hostels / Barracks:202948 sq ft}

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of two storey hostel for 150 law \& drill staff:22742 sq ft }

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Administration Block:5433 sq ft}

\end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Project Scope Continued...}
\begin{block}{Construction of Principal Office: 5400 sq ft}

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of two storey Dining hall for male trainees: 960 sq ft}

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of shops and canteen:3175 sq ft}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Dispensary: 2115 sq ft}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Sheds for Vehicles: 4495 sq ft}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Project Scope Continued...}
\begin{block}{Construction of Mess and Recreation for females: 3930 sq ft}

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Guest Speaker accommodation: 3120 sq ft}

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Fire fighting and Garage: 1120 sq ft  }

\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Multi Storey Residence for BPS 1 to 10 :  7920 sq ft }
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of Multi Storey Residence for BPS 11 to 14 :   5440 sq ft }
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Project Scope Continued...}
\begin{block}{Construction of Multi Storey Residence for BPS 15 to 17:  3300 sq ft}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction of one Residence for BPS 18 to 19:           3150 sq ft}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Provision of G.I pipe 5 inch diameter water supply line:  1500 sq ft}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Construction  of  Over  Head  Reservior 20000 Glns Capacity:      20,000 sq ft}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Administration Block}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Cost Comparison}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{PDWP Submission }
\begin{block}{ Project is submitted for consideration of PDWP.}

\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This can hardly be a **minimal** working example. And your question should be part of the body, instead of appearing only at the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\section{\insertframetitle}}` just before `begin{document}`, this will create a ToC with all your frametitles:

[image]

Comment: Thank u very much for the solution. Best Wishes for U!

Comment: Here i want to remove the header headings. and contents  is at no.1.It looks awkward

Comment: @MUHAMMADIBRARHUSSAIN Contents is a frame title and hence it is added, as you requested. If you don't want this, you can set the beamer template after the contents frame. I don't get the rest of your sentence, I propose to clarify the question and improve it before going forward.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You have nailed it. Weldone!

Comment: \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\section[]{\insertframetitle}}
 i have added [] to remove frame titles from header.